# Convert HttpPostedFileBase - pdf type to png/jpg type

Tags: c#, .net, converters

I get HttpPostedFileBase of pdf type. 
How do i convert this file type to a png/jpg file type?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2995984/2091410](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2995984/2091410). You'll need to get PDFSharp, but it's free. I've used it for creating PDF's, and the only problem is that PDFSharp has a *lot* of features. It can be a challenge to zero in on the area of functionality you need, but once you do it's generally straightforward.

Comment: i try this one: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx
but when i try to open the jpg file, pop up alert: "... the file appears to be damage, corrupted, ot is too large"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best free and easy project i've found and that is working great is:
http://mattmeisinger.com/convert-pdf-to-image

**PAY ATTENTION:** if you have problems with gsdll32.dll or gsdll64.dll look where import the dll into the project and change it to your own dll path.